# finding first empty row to adjust the range in formal

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is an UPDATE:

I have the formal below which i want to change range D4:D8 to D4:First empty cell in D. Basically i need to make my range dynamical and not limited to D8

```
 =IF(
  COUNTIF(D4:D8;"Completion delayed")>0;"Completion delayed";IF(
  COUNTIF(D4:D8;"Start delayed")>0;"Start delayed";IF(
  COUNTIF(D4:D8;"In progress")>0;"In progress";IF(
  AND(COUNTIF(D4:D8;"Not started")>0;COUNTIF(D4:D8;"Done")>0);"In progress";IF(
  COUNTIF(D4:D8;"Not started")>0;"Not started";IF(
  COUNTIF(D4:D8;"Done")>0;"Done";"N/A"
))))))
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: why did you tage this with `VBA` ? you have a regular formula

Comment: thanks Shai Rado for your response, now I have edited it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: `=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A:A="",0),0)` gives you the row number of the first empty row in column A.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. How can i insert this in my formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(
  COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D4:D" & A1);"Completion delayed")>0;"Completion delayed";IF(
  COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D4:D" & A1);"Start delayed")>0;"Start delayed";IF(
  COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D4:D" & A1);"In progress")>0;"In progress";IF(
  AND(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D4:D" & A1);"Not started")>0;COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D4:D" & A1);"Done")>0);"In progress";IF(
  COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D4:D" & A1);"Not started")>0;"Not started";IF(
  COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D4:D" & A1);"Done")>0;"Done";"N/A"
))))))
```

Comment: I have list of events so Event 1 starts from D4 until D8. Then Event 2 starts from D10 to d 14. But i can add other rows in Event 1 so D4 to last row must be dynamic until it finds an empty cell, which means Event 2 starts

Comment: Adding to reply below, your formula will be like below

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I receive #REF error.

Comment: Use in cell A1    =MATCH(TRUE;D4:D1048576="";0)+3. After entering this value in cell A1 use (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) instead of Enter

Comment: one question regarding the new rows. This formula makes the range according to the last empty row dynamically. When i want to use the same formula after say D8. When i add a row before D8, this makes my next range start from D9 until next empty row again. How can i use your formula to find second empty row? Should i use the same formula in A2 or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Get number of first empty row

```
=MATCH(TRUE;D4:D1048576="";0)+3
```

as ArrayFormula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) in other cell (for example A1) and use it to get correct reference by INDIRECT

```
(...) COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D4:D" & A1);"Completion delayed")>0 (...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. How should i combine this in my formel, do you know this?

Comment: you could do something like COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D4:D" & MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(D4:D1048576="";0);0)+3);"Completion delayed")>0 but it would be slower.

Comment: the problem is i will have dnyamic range yes from d4 to say d12, d13 and so on. But i need then to use the same formula after d15 to say d19, d20 and so on. So the formula should only search from d4 to first empty row. Then from another dynamic D value to first empty cell after this

Comment: Maybe you could add column with formula like =IF(D4="";D3+1;D3) and then use its values to determine part of table by changing COUNTIF to COUNTIFS(A$4:A$1000;A4;D$4:D$1000;"Completion delayed")>0